# Creating an array from JSON data of file/directory locations; bash not registering if element is a directory

Tags: arrays, json, bash

I have a JSON file which holds data like this: `"path/to/git/directory/location": "path/to/local/location"`.  A minimum example of the file might be this:

```
{
    "${HOME}/dotfiles/.bashrc": "${HOME}/.bashrc",
    "${HOME}/dotfiles/.atom/": "${HOME}/.atom/"
}
```

I have a script that systematically reads the above JSON (called `locations.json`) and creates an array, and then prints elements of the array that are directories.  MWE:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

unset sysarray
declare -A sysarray

while IFS=: read -r field data
do
    sysarray["${field}"]="${data}"
done <<< $(sed  '/^[{}]$/d;s/\s*"/"/g;s/,$//' locations.json)

for file in "${sysarray[@]}"
do
    if [ -d "${file}" ] 
    then
        echo "${file}"
    fi
done
```

However, this does not print the directory (i.e., ${HOME}/.atom).
I don't understand why this is happening, because

- I have tried creating an array manually (i.e., not from a JSON) and checking if its elements are directories, and that works fine.
- I have tried echoing each element in the array into a temporary file and reading each line in the file to see if it was a product of how the information was stored in the array, but no luck.
- I have tried adding  `| tr -d "[:blank:]" | tr -d '\"'` after using `sed` on the JSON (to see if it was a product of unintended whitespace or quotes), but no luck.
- I have tried simply running `[ -d "${HOME}/.atom/" ] && echo '.atom is a directory'`, and that works (so indeed it is a directory).  I'm unsure what might be causing this.

Help on this would be great!

Comment: Two comments: a) which is the problem? What is happenning? b) the provided data is not a valid JSON.

Comment: @Poshi I have fixed the JSON file, sorry.  The problem is that it is not registering when the given file location is a directory and when is it not.

Comment: Which is the output of `echo "${file}"`? It reads what you expect to be read? I bet you are getting the quotes, the commas...

Comment: @Poshi the output of `echo "${file}"` is as expected:
```
${HOME}/.bashrc
${HOME}/.atom/
```

Comment: I just run your code, and I can see what I already told you: the output is not as expected. The output contains quotes. And your actual files does not contain quotes.

Comment: @Poshi see my third point at the end of my question, and notice that removing the quotes doesn’t change the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a tool to process json files properly, which will deal with any valid json.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

unset sysarray
declare -A sysarray

while IFS="=" read -r field data
do
    sysarray["${field}"]=$(eval echo "${data}")
done <<< $(jq -r 'keys[] as $k | "\($k)=\(.[$k])"' locations.json)

for file in "${sysarray[@]}"
do
    if [ -d "${file}" ] 
    then
        echo "${file}"
    fi
done
```

Another problem is that, once the extra quote signs are properly processed, we have a literal `${HOME}` that is not expanded. The only solution I came is using `eval` to force the expansion. It is not the nicest way, but right now I cannot find a better solution.

Comment: That must be what was happening in my code above.  I thought that it was only single quotes that didn't expand variables.
Thank you for your help.  The `eval` isn't pretty, but it works, so thank you.

Comment: Only single quotes does not expand variables. The point is that the variables are expanded when the string is created in the shell. And in your code, it is being read by `read`, not performing any expansion and storing the literals.

Comment: Read reads contents literally. If it hits a dollar sign... you get a dollar sign.